# The "docker stats" Command Shows CPU over 100%

Tags: docker, grafana, prometheus

Why does `docker stats` show CPU values of over 100%?

I had configured Grafana and Prometheus to monitor our Docker containers and noticed that the CPU dial was above 100% (E.g., 274.87%). This obviously has to be invalid since the CPU should not ever exceed 100%. I figured the problem wasn't with Prometheus as it just collects data so I took a look at docker stats which does show multiple containers running at a higher CPU than 100%.

One is showing 864.22%! Are there any ideas? It will be hard to sell others on this system if it is not reporting correctly even if it is Docker's fault and not Prometheus.

```
b6ca088bd36f        864.22%             145.6MiB / 31.38GiB   0.45%               809kB / 0B          1.08GB / 60.7GB     13
```

```
myuser@myserver:/opt/grafana-prometheus$ docker stats --no-stream --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}\t{{.MemUsage}}\t{{.MemPerc}}\t{{.NetIO}}\t{{.BlockIO}}\t{{.PIDs}}"
CONTAINER ID        CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
3aa1b1ee6e19        1.44%               108.7MiB / 31.38GiB   0.34%               62.5MB / 1.91MB     3.87MB / 0B         27
100f43fad3ab        33.25%              128.6MiB / 31.38GiB   0.40%               945kB / 57.3MB      0B / 0B             38
0ac96cc007b5        0.03%               30.85MiB / 31.38GiB   0.10%               4.65MB / 8.35MB     0B / 18.2MB         26
6b0e97f7e724        0.08%               3.055MiB / 31.38GiB   0.01%               1.66kB / 0B         0B / 0B             4
c73fb64316a7        20.31%              19.89MiB / 31.38GiB   0.06%               134kB / 4.86MB      2.75MB / 0B         39
9789baadfd00        0.00%               7.164MiB / 31.38GiB   0.02%               24.5kB / 2.3MB      12.9MB / 0B         5
a71d00ccf435        0.00%               8.52MiB / 31.38GiB    0.03%               1.76MB / 963kB      680kB / 0B          2
f404766b0661        0.07%               6.047MiB / 31.38GiB   0.02%               7.92GB / 6.06GB     3.24MB / 0B         1
35c262f7d578        13.67%              1.115GiB / 31.38GiB   3.55%               3.04TB / 264GB      6.59GB / 2.07GB     17
df7c4ab8d05a        0.00%               37.04MiB / 31.38GiB   0.12%               332MB / 183MB       47.8MB / 8.19kB     18
1079691ced88        22.10%              314.2MiB / 31.38GiB   0.98%               2.18TB / 222GB      31.4GB / 29.5GB     8
ce4699287e5b        0.00%               77.75MiB / 31.38GiB   0.24%               61GB / 18.8GB       927MB / 78MB        4
448a6b27df90        0.00%               8.836MiB / 31.38GiB   0.03%               3.94GB / 1.28GB     5.08MB / 0B         7
9fc4b8d7eaa5        9.21%               480.6MiB / 31.38GiB   1.50%               134GB / 2.82TB      76.1GB / 1.91TB     51
e169b18b9e18        0.02%               45.25MiB / 31.38GiB   0.14%               71.1MB / 54.7MB     56.7MB / 6.02MB     10
200e4dd14258        10.04%              151.5MiB / 31.38GiB   0.47%               57.3GB / 198GB      35.4MB / 1.37TB     4
c4bf2af973b6        0.00%               42.62MiB / 31.38GiB   0.13%               1.26GB / 77.3MB     19.6MB / 8.19kB     10
5275f51e0d67        0.30%               115MiB / 31.38GiB     0.36%               77.4MB / 1.32GB     93.3MB / 8.02GB     28
ba921d36ba50        0.00%               31.12MiB / 31.38GiB   0.10%               332MB / 183MB       42.3MB / 8.19kB     16
d32e55c339c3        0.00%               9.84MiB / 31.38GiB    0.03%               1.22MB / 1.48MB     9.73MB / 0B         2
08c62a2d03ab        0.28%               143.1MiB / 31.38GiB   0.45%               4.17GB / 6.26GB     27.7MB / 57.3kB     11
d7830b42d157        0.14%               2.262MiB / 31.38GiB   0.01%               4.89GB / 3.62GB     197kB / 0B          1
8b30b0a206c9        0.02%               34.17MiB / 31.38GiB   0.11%               886kB / 2.08MB      4.37MB / 147kB      9
3a332472da76        0.12%               122.4MiB / 31.38GiB   0.38%               1.55GB / 887MB      9.32MB / 348GB      4
58077ea4b082        0.06%               253MiB / 31.38GiB     0.79%               540kB / 3.22MB      142MB / 153MB       30
2894fd5d1e4d        0.00%               20.55MiB / 31.38GiB   0.06%               578kB / 0B          157MB / 129MB       3
53cbc0e871df        0.00%               8.121MiB / 31.38GiB   0.03%               101MB / 51.5MB      1.24MB / 0B         7
8ee607007e29        0.00%               64.38MiB / 31.38GiB   0.20%               42.8MB / 82.4MB     38.9MB / 1.51MB     4
8361042fb46d        0.23%               47.14MiB / 31.38GiB   0.15%               125kB / 0B          12.9MB / 7.61GB     26
d379c40f3170        0.00%               30.04MiB / 31.38GiB   0.09%               784kB / 60.9kB      16MB / 0B           10
b63fad3f97db        0.23%               46.72MiB / 31.38GiB   0.15%               1.13MB / 16.4MB     22.2MB / 7.61GB     26
b4dbeab1ff03        0.06%               3.05GiB / 31.38GiB    9.72%               56.1GB / 1.07TB     8.3GB / 29.2GB      48
0f95c759e0b6        120.35%             8.782GiB / 31.38GiB   27.98%              235GB / 1.2TB       9.79GB / 1.03TB     51
304a44684bf3        0.21%               3.758GiB / 31.38GiB   11.97%              3.94GB / 8.24GB     2.45GB / 23.9GB     27
cd7b0670f6ad        0.00%               9.344MiB / 31.38GiB   0.03%               1.72MB / 1.86MB     20.5MB / 0B         2
8beb3f42046a        0.00%               1.832MiB / 31.38GiB   0.01%               809kB / 0B          24.6kB / 0B         1
b6ca088bd36f        864.22%             145.6MiB / 31.38GiB   0.45%               809kB / 0B          1.08GB / 60.7GB     13
e91017608575        0.00%               32.59MiB / 31.38GiB   0.10%               538MB / 296MB       34.7MB / 8.19kB     17
f821730e7ae2        0.00%               61.62MiB / 31.38GiB   0.19%               1.14GB / 8.92MB     14.5MB / 229kB      4
760a476ac1fa        0.00%               9.523MiB / 31.38GiB   0.03%               3.27MB / 2.18MB     7.18MB / 0B         7
0c8abcd7fef8        0.05%               38.22MiB / 31.38GiB   0.12%               6.95MB / 1.14GB     223MB / 34.8MB      29
7af2e3f2447d        0.02%               26.84MiB / 31.38GiB   0.08%               1.21MB / 4.01MB     3.31MB / 24.6kB     9
0004b7a7905a        0.08%               107.9MiB / 31.38GiB   0.34%               297MB / 537MB       3.97MB / 361GB      4
d505d2b67553        0.00%               34.19MiB / 31.38GiB   0.11%               1.16MB / 340kB      10.3MB / 0B         10
b4bd6dc9139d        0.21%               46.45MiB / 31.38GiB   0.14%               157kB / 0B          21.9MB / 12.4GB     26
046f1826a598        0.00%               7.785MiB / 31.38GiB   0.02%               4.64GB / 2.4GB      213MB / 0B          2
4dfaa4076961        0.00%               193.1MiB / 31.38GiB   0.60%               5.31MB / 31.9MB     0B / 68.1MB         21
400c170c2690        0.30%               23.09MiB / 31.38GiB   0.07%               1.17MB / 389kB      2.53GB / 1.44MB     35
30d4821cec59        0.12%               55.2MiB / 31.38GiB    0.17%               8.17GB / 10.1GB     114MB / 407MB       66
b7b1e39c002c        0.00%               2.383MiB / 31.38GiB   0.01%               621kB / 0B          8.86MB / 0B         5
03d761c40e38        0.00%               10.74MiB / 31.38GiB   0.03%               1.32GB / 1.03GB     15.8MB / 0B         5
6e4ab551f915        0.00%               198.7MiB / 31.38GiB   0.62%               489kB / 203kB       0B / 37.4MB         21
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CPU usage is 100% when a single processor would be fully utilized. With multiple processors, this number will exceed 100%, you need to multiply by the number of processors available to the host to find the theoretical upper limit.

Some tools also show system load rather than CPU utilization, which are very different in Linux. System load increases as processes are waiting to run, so you can be at 500% load on a single CPU system if there are 5 processes that all want to run 100% of the time.